# Sync/Update computer clock with a timeserver using NTPClient

Tags: c#, ntp

I am trying to sync the computers clock using a server. I have googled around and found that "NTPClient" could be used for this.

My goal is to sync the computer time with below time server:
**time.nist.gov**

Below are the links from where I have got the library and code to use as seen in my code:

**Source to get NTPClient.cs file**
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1005/SNTP-Client-in-C

**Source of below code**   
         https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_date_time/timeroutines/article.php/c4207/C-SNTP-Client.htm

When I run the code, I get an image like below, where it retreive the correct time:
[image]

I think but are not sure that the important line is:
**client.Connect(true);**

as the intellisense says that "true" means to "UpdateSystemTime" but that doesn't happen, so I beleive I am not sure how to do this?

```
void synccomputerTime()
{
    //https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1005/SNTP-Client-in-C (Source to get NTPClient.cs file)
    //https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_date_time/timeroutines/article.php/c4207/C-SNTP-Client.htm (Source of below code)
    NTPClient client;
    try
    {
        client = new NTPClient("time.nist.gov");
        client.Connect(true); //true should UpdateSystemTime but doesn't do that?
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ERROR: {0}", e.Message);
        return;
    }
    MessageBox.Show(client.ToString());
}
```

......................................................

I have also tried using this class with no luck: 
**SNTPClient.cs**
https://github.com/ramonsmits/InternetTime/blob/master/SNTPClient.cs

Here I also set this line to true as it should update the computer clock but doesn't do that: 
**sntp.Connect(true); // true to update local client clock**

```
void synccomputerTime2()
{
    //https://github.com/ramonsmits/InternetTime/blob/master/SNTPClient.cs
    InternetTime.SNTPClient sntp = new InternetTime.SNTPClient("ntp1.ja.net");
    sntp.Connect(true); // true to update local client clock
    DateTime dt = sntp.DestinationTimestamp.AddMilliseconds(sntp.LocalClockOffset);
    string timeStampNow = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff");
    MessageBox.Show(timeStampNow);
}
```

Comment: FY: I don't know what your motivation and your goal is, but note that the OS itself can maintain time using an NTP server.

Comment: I use a library where it is critically important to send along requests with an exact time that need to match their servertime. So just 1000 ms off will result in an error. So I need to sync the computer clock ever 15 minutes to be on the safe side. "time.nist.gov" seems to be a safe bet in my case as I have understood. In what way can the OS do this and is it possible to do this from C# using NTP?

Comment: I have edited my first post with another approach using SNTPClient with no success either.

Comment: Windows already has a ntp client built in (W32Time).

Comment: There's no need. It updates on a schedule all on it's own. It's all automatic.

Answer (score 0):

Windows already has an NTP client built in (`W32Time`). Just do this from and administrator command prompt:

```
net time /setsntp:time.nist.gov
```

If you're on a business network joined to an Active Directory domain, your computer is by default already syncing time with your domain controller, and you don't want to change this.

Comment: I tried both those commands in the cmd runned as an administrator but nothing is happening to the clock(which I have manually put 10 minutes wrong): net time /set sntp:time.nist.gov and net time /setsntp:time.nist.gov (I use Windows 10 Pro) I can just see a lot of information coming up in the command prompt about NET TIME syncronization information etc.

Comment: I can see this message coming up which seems to be a problem? "The /QUERYSNTP and /SETSNTP options have been deprecated. Please use w32tm.exe
to configure the Windows Time Service."

Comment: If I run this command in the command prompt as an administrator. It do sync the computerclock: "w32tm /resync" But I would need to execute this from C#. How can I do that?